# How to install TimescaleDB extension for postgress database with entity framework core

Tags: postgresql, ef-core-2.2, timescaledb

I want to use [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) on a specific table containing time-series data. The question I have is how to setup time-series from entity framework core and make a specific table a [hyper table](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/hypertables)?

Database: Postgress version 11
Framework: Ef Core 2.2
Method: Code First

Comment: Do you create create your schema manually, or you let Entity create it for you? If you create it yourself, and Entity just connects to the database, then you can simply execute `SELECT create_hypertable('table_name'...)` and Entity will have no problem working with 'table_name'. If Entity creates your db schema, then you can create a custom database initializer, and after the db is created, execute a raw query `SELECT create_hypertable...`

Comment: I create my scheme manually, with models, and do a migration from there. I will have a look at the database initializer, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TimonPost any idea how to do this in ef core since it doesnt have database initializers?

Comment: @psclkhoury you should have: 1) one date-time field in your model. 2) In postgress db you should install the timescale plugin with `CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb;` SQL command. 3) Call `dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT create_hypertable('device_points', 'Datetime');");` on database creation.

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution for code-first EF. It is pretty straight forward.

1) Add one date-time field in your model of the table you want to scale with timescale db.

2) Install the timescale plugin for Postgres.

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb;
```

3) Execute the following SQL in a database seeder or initializer.

```sql
dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT create_hypertable('table_name', 'datetime_field_name');");
```

*(`datetime_field_name` is a required datetime field for timescale db (see 1))*